# WinRT - Why can't this String (array of Char) be round-tripped?

Tags: c#, unicode, windows-runtime

Note: This is Windows RT! I was so amazed that this doesn't work that I tried it in LinqPad and its fine.

Look at the output from the VS Immediate Window:

```
string str = "503";
"503"

var charArray = str.ToCharArray();
{char[3]}
    [0]: 53 '5'
    [1]: 48 '0'
    [2]: 51 '3'

string str2 = new String(charArray);
'new String(charArray)' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentException'

new String(charArray);
'new String(charArray)' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentException'
    base: {"Value does not fall within the expected range."}
    m_paramName: null
    Message: "Value does not fall within the expected range."
    ParamName: null
```

What's going on here?

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't throw an exception on me. What is your environments by the way?

Comment: Yep. Spot on, its WinRT.

Comment: I can reproduce it in the *Immediate* window of the debugger. Executing it normally works.

Comment: Brilliant, you're right. I'll submit a Connect bug.

Comment: This is not specific to RT nor the specific constructor.  Note how `new string(' ', 3);` fails the same way.  Do keep in mind that the Immediate Window does not use a full-blown compiler, Roslyn won't happen until VS-next.  I suspect it is a restriction due to these constructors being internal CLR calls.  This isn't going to get fixed today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed a bug in the VS expression evaluator (used by the Immediate Window).  The issue has been fixed for Visual Studio 2015 (you can try out the latest CTP, including the fix, [here](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-vs.aspx)).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Dirk pointing out that it actually does execute when coded in the Windows Store app itself. I'm classing it as a bug in the VS IDE.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1019365